# Why does `stringsAsFactors` use capital letters for readability in R?

Tags: r

Why does `stringsAsFactors` use capital letters to aid readability in `R` when most other commands seem to use `.` (e.g., `as.factor`)?

Is this an idiosyncrasy or part of a higher organizaton of the commands that I am not familiar with?

Is there any way to predict which commands will use capital letters and which will use `.`?

Thanks

Comment: You would need to ask the R-core member(s) who wrote those functions.  It's not documented why some functions use camelCase, some use under_scores, and some use "." (other than S3 methods).

Comment: Sometimes `_` is also used as a separator, just to make it even more confusing.

Comment: I think it is worth stressing that `stringsAsFactors` is an **argument** name and `as.factor()` is a function name.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson, so are the words in arguments delineated by "caps" and those in functions by "dots"?  That would be the type of pattern I am wondering about.

Comment: No, not at all. If you look at `args(read.table)` you'll see a mix of argument names using `.` as a separator and the camel case of `stringsAsFactors`. As I mention in my Answer, `.` is not generally used in base R for new functions these days, to avoid the confusion over S3 generics. But R desires to remain backwards compatible with itself and S etc, so there are some functions that will forever remain with a name including a `.` but aren't an S3 generic/method. YThere aren't strict rules, except that perhaps don't use `.` in function names unless they are S3 generics/methods.

Comment: The same can be said also of argument names; the mix in read.table arises because of compatibility with S/S-PLUS and the more recent addition of new argument names and new options in R (`stringsAsFactors` is a new option in R. If you want to see an example of the mess, read `?options` and see all the various styles used there!

Comment: @Gavin Simpson Thanks for the clarification.  My R experience is fairly narrow, so I didn't know if I was overlooking a pattern that would help me keep it all straight.

Comment: remember when _ was also used for assignment . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of the idiosyncrasies arise because of the heritage from the S language and compatibility with the implementation in S-PLUS. There has been a tendency in recent years to avoid new functions with names that include a `.` as a separator to avoid confusion with S3 methods. This hasn't been change retrospectively because of backwards compatibility and a desire to be faithful to functions from S/S-PLUS days.

Since `_` was deprecated as an alternative to `<-`, some authors have used it in function names; an example are packages of Hadley Wickham, but there are plenty of others.

The lack of a strictly adhered standard can be confusing, and certainly adds to the learning curve, but is something you have to live with.

Answer (score 4):

It is obvious -- no standard has been established before it was too late ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The so-called 'camelCase' is a good choice.

Besides Hadley, few recommend underscores.  See for example the [Google R Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google-r-style.html) which says:

> Don't use underscores ( _ ) or hyphens ( - ) in identifiers.

R itself does not enforce a style, but (heuristically speaking) not too many new core libraries use a dot either as a separator in identifiers as this is also used for 
S3 methods.

Comment: Hyphens are much worse than underscores. The latter is a stylistic choice, the former can't even be used without jumping through hoops (like protecting symbol names with backticks).

Comment: I can understand not using '-' since that is "syntactically active" but the deprecation of underscores doesn't seem justified. (I know this wasn't your advice, but you are repeating it.) The advantage that underscores offer me is that a double-click in my editing environment selects all of a name with undercores, but breaks on "."

Comment: I don't disagree with either of you, and didn't really say anything about hyphens -- which are obviously **really** bad. But in my little world (and, seemingly, also in Google's) underscores are seen as pretty evil too.  And that was my point.

Comment: @DWin `_` in function/argument names is a pain in *my* editor (Emacs/ESS) as it requires me to make two presses of `_` to get a `_` (one press gives `<-`). That's why I don't like them and I find using packages that employ them a struggle with learned editing behaviour. Just a different view on things. I too don't want to see `_` deprecated, but just because an editing environment isn't as useful without it isn't a strong justification for keeping it.

Comment: @DWin: where's the "double-click" button on the keyboard? ;-)

Comment: @DWin, Gavin Seems your editors just have poor configurability (-;